# How to fetch data from MSSQL Query for DataTables using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server, ajax, datatable

This is the code that i get from [DataTables Child Rows](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "../ajax/data/objects.txt", //here
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            }, //and here to fetch the data below
            { "data": "name" }, 
            { "data": "position" }, 
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );
```

I would like to get the data from an SQL Query by using ajax. This is my SQL Query :

```
$tsql = 
"SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[ITEM_MASTER] A
INNER JOIN
[dbo].[STOCK] B
ON
B.ItemId = A.ItemId
";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));
if (!$result) {
 die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{
    $ItmId = $row['ItemId'];
    $ItmName = $row['ItemName'];
    $ItmType = $row['ItemType'];
    $ItmGroup = $row['ItemGroup'];
    $ItmClass = $row['ItemClass'];
    $ItmSerialNum = $row['ItemSerialNum'];
    $ItmUOM = $row['ItemUOM'];
    $StkQty = $row['StockQuantity'];
    $StkId = $row['StockId'];
 }
```

And on the ajax part, i just call the name of the variable like `$ItmId` or like i've stated in my while loop.
Is it possible? If so, how? Since i don't have any knowledge on AJAX

---

**UPDATE**

The data were pushed to the second parameter and is not showing the `ItmId` ? And no matter if i change `$data : ItmName` it just displays based on the arrays and display something else?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#table').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "url": "table_data.php",
            "type": "POST"
            },
        "columns": [
            {
                "class":          'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "$data": "ItmId"  },
            { "$data": "ItmName" },
            { "$data": "ItmGroup"},
            { "$data": "ItmClass"}
    ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );
```

Comment: You need to make a json object and add the data to a `data` array within that json response.

Comment: @Darren Can u give me an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you need to change this line:

```
"ajax": "../ajax/data/objects.txt", //here
```

to point to the actual file that will run the sql query to fetch the data: i.e. like this:

```
"ajax": {"url": "path/to/phpfile.php", "type": "POST"}
```

You need to make your `while` loop like this:

```
$data = array();
while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{
    $ItmId = $row['ItemId'];
    $ItmName = $row['ItemName'];
    $ItmType = $row['ItemType'];
    $ItmGroup = $row['ItemGroup'];
    $ItmClass = $row['ItemClass'];
    $ItmSerialNum = $row['ItemSerialNum'];
    $ItmUOM = $row['ItemUOM'];
    $StkQty = $row['StockQuantity'];
    $StkId = $row['StockId'];

    $data['data'][] = array($ItmId, $ItmName, $ItmType,....etc);
 }
 echo json_encode($data);
```

You should note, you require the exactly amount of columns in your actual table (html).
Also, your json should look like this:

```
data:
    array(
        ItmId,
        ItmName,
        ..etc
    ),
    array(
        ItmId,
        ItmName,
        ..etc
    ),
```

Essentially have an array of rows.

Comment: so on this part `"ajax": "../ajax/data/objects.txt"` and `{ "data": "name" }`, how should i fetch the data then?

Comment: the `data : array( ItmId, ItmName,......),` is supposed to be replacing the `{ "data": "name" }` ?

Comment: No, you should remove that from your `dataTables` piece of JS code.

Comment: I'm sorry but i have to get rid all of that? Can u show me :(

Comment: wait, why is it `POST` ? I mean i want to retrieve the data and display in a table. i'm confused.

Comment: It doesn't matter cause you aren't sending any input to the script so it an be `post` or `get`. Neither will change it. (For completion sake you would use `get` but it doesn't matter.)

Comment: Apologies, I see the way you were making the table, you can keep the data keys in there exactly like it is in the example. Are there any errors, is the data showing?

Comment: Darren, i've solved it. Thanks for your guidance! But i have to alter the code on my while loop that's all

Answer (score 1):

Based on Darren's answer, i solved it like this:

**table_data.php**

```
    $data = array();

    while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $data['data'][] = array(
                        'ItmId'          => $row['ItemId'],
                        'ItmName'        => $row['ItemName'],
                        'ItmType'        => $row['ItemType'],
                        'ItmGroup'       => $row['ItemGroup'],
                        'ItmClass'       => $row['ItemClass'],
                        'ItmSerialNum'   => $row['ItemSerialNum'],
                        'ItmUOM'         => $row['ItemUOM'],
                        'StkQty'         => $row['StockQuantity'],
                        'StkId'          => $row['StockId']
                        );

    }

   echo json_encode($data);
```

**table.php** (where i display my html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#table').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "url": "table_data.php",
            "type": "POST"
            },
        "columns": [
            {
                "class":          'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "ItmId"},
            { "data": "ItmName"},
            { "data": "ItmClass"},
            { "data": "ItmUOM"}
    ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );
```