# DataTable fetch modified data from row

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, datatables

I have a problem with printing the right content from a row in my datatble.

i have a file called <kbd>response.php</kbd> with the following content:

```
//include connection file
session_start();
include_once("connection.php");

// initilize all variable
$params = $columns = $totalRecords = $data = array();
$params = $_REQUEST;

//define index of column
$columns = array( 
    0 =>'log_in_timestamp',
    1 =>'liDateInserted',
    2 => 'browser',
    3 => 'location',
    4 => 'lo_li_time'
);

$where = $sqlTot = $sqlRec = "";

// check search value exist
if( !empty($params['search']['value']) ) {   
    $where .=" WHERE ";
    $where .=" ( browser LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";
    $where .=" OR location LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";
    $where .=" AND ut.id = '".$_SESSION["userSession"]."%' ";
}

// getting total number records without any search
$sql = "SELECT li.log_in_timestamp, li.date_inserted liDateInserted, li.browser, li.location, (lo.log_out_timestamp - li.log_in_timestamp) lo_li_time, li.user_who_used_the_session, li.id historyId,
        lo.id, lo.user_who_used_the_session, lo.log_out_timestamp, lo.date_inserted, ut.id, ut.username
        FROM log_in_user_sessions li 
        LEFT JOIN log_out_user_sessions lo ON li.unique_id_login = lo.unique_id_logout 
        LEFT JOIN user_table ut ON li.user_who_used_the_session = ut.username
        WHERE ut.id = '".$_SESSION["userSession"]."'";
$sqlTot .= $sql;
$sqlRec .= $sql;

//concatenate search sql if value exist
if(isset($where) && $where != '') {

    $sqlTot .= $where;
    $sqlRec .= $where;
}


$sqlRec .=  " ORDER BY ". $columns[$params['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$params['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$params['start']." ,".$params['length']." ";

$queryTot = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlTot) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));


$totalRecords = mysqli_num_rows($queryTot);

$queryRecords = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlRec) or die("error to fetch employees data");

//iterate on results row and create new index array of data
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($queryRecords) ) {
    $data[] = $row;
}   

$json_data = array(
        "draw"            => intval( $params['draw'] ),   
        "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalRecords ),  
        "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalRecords),
        "data"            => $data   // total data array
        );

echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format
```

now in my <kbd>index.php</kbd>
i call the table like this:

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="">
                    <h3>User Sessions</h3><br>
                    <div class="">
                        <table id="employee_grid" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Time</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Browser</th>
                                <th>Location</th>
                                <th>Duration</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Time</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Browser</th>
                                <th>Location</th>
                                <th>Duration</th>

                            </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

i've tried the `js` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#employee_grid').DataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "columnDefs": [
                { "width": "20%", "defaultContent": "Not Logged Out","targets": "_all" }
            ],
            "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
            // Bold the grade for all 'A' grade browsers
                if (!aData[4])
                {
                    $(nRow).addClass( 'alert-danger' ).css('background-color', '#f2dede');
                }
            },
            "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            "responsive": true,
            "ajax":{
                url :"../test/dt/dt_i/response.php",
                type: "post",
                error: function() {
                    $("#employee_grid_processing").css("display", "none");
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

my output looks like this:[image: current output]

i've created the same thing for my own in `php` and it looks like this. I want the DataTable to look like this:
[image: look i want]

i've tried to get my knowledge from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500778/how-to-fetch-json-data-from-php-for-datatables-jquery-plugin), [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) or [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/14563/change-css-row-with-fnrowcallback)

**My question now is, how can i output the right formatted data like the `unixtimestamp` with the right css background in my 2nd picture**

## Edit:

i changed my sql statement to:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(li.log_in_timestamp, '%H:%i'), DATE(li.date_inserted) liDateInserted, li.browser, li.location, FROM_UNIXTIME((lo.log_out_timestamp - li.log_in_timestamp), '%H:%i:%sh') lo_li_time, li.user_who_used_the_session, li.id historyId,
    lo.id, lo.user_who_used_the_session, lo.log_out_timestamp, lo.date_inserted, ut.id, ut.username
    FROM log_in_user_sessions li 
    LEFT JOIN log_out_user_sessions lo ON li.unique_id_login = lo.unique_id_logout 
    LEFT JOIN user_table ut ON li.user_who_used_the_session = ut.username
    WHERE ut.id = '" . $_SESSION["userSession"] . "'
```

and now everything is correctly formatted, but with the css-background is still a problem...
[image: current]

**Can someone correct this lines here ?:**

```
"fnRowCallback": function(column, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                // Bold the grade for all 'A' grade browsers
                if (!aData[4])
                {
                    $(column).addClass( 'alert-danger' ).css('background-color', '#f2dede');
                }
            },
```

Comment: In 2nd pic you are showing date under time column and time under date column, why is it so ?

Comment: yeah i have to change that btw. thanks for the info

Comment: @MayankPandeyz updated it :)

Comment: All you need to do is format the timestamp as you want to see it using `date()` or the DateTime object

Comment: Now you want to convert the timestamp to time and extract date part of datetime?

Comment: yeah but how can i fetch the values ? can you give me an anser ? i tried at the response.php data[] = $row and placed there an array with my values but it wont work... the datatable continued with not working

Comment: @MayankPandeyz yeah i know its like in php with the date() functiion, but i dont know how to get the values from the array. can you give me a possible answer ?

Comment: i've tried it like this `$data[] = array("name" => $row["name"],"time" => $result);`

Comment: how can i fetch them in `javascript` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get time from timestamp like:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1447430881);
-> '2015-11-13 10:08:01'
```

put FROM_UNIXTIME on your timestamp column and get time.

And to get date from datetime use EXTRACT like:

```
SELECT DATE(datetime) from table;
```

put both these in your query check the result.

Comment: thanks :) ill try that one, but im looking for something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27558950/5930557 can you update your answer with the right php file and js file. would really appreciate that :)